# Get locale Infomation in php

Tags: php

I need to get the **thousand marker** and **decimel marker** for a locale. Currently I have got the `localeconv` function for getting the same. But it only give the details of the current locale that have been set via `setlocale` function.
 So one option is to
 1. Get the current locale and save it
 2. Then set the locale to the one I want and get the details
 3. After that reset to my original locale.

I there any other method to get the locale information other that switching between the locales.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a 3rd-party library, such as [Symfony's Intl Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html).

Comment: Actually I am working on symfony2 and is using the `intl` component, but i didn't found any function which will return the `thousand marker` and `decimal marker` for a given locale

Comment: Have you tried using [NumberFormatter](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Intl/NumberFormatter/NumberFormatter.html)? In fact, if you have PECL intl (http://pecl.php.net/package/intl), the Class (as well as procedural functions) are already included (see http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.format.php).